# Listar dados de outra collection no firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Tenho 2 collections, uma chamada Communities e outra Fellow.

Qual o intuito delas? Uma pessoa pode fazer parte dessa comunidade, para poder seguir esses conteúdos

Quando a pessoa clica em seguir uma comunidade, salva no firebase, na collection Member as informações dos usuários que está seguindo
e também as informações da comunidade, pois assim permite que um usuário siga várias comunidades ao mesmo tempo e comunidades tenham vários usuários
ao mesmo tempo.

Na collection Member, temos

```
memberAtive (boolean) - se está ativo na comunidade ou não
memberCommunity (String) - nome da comunidade
memberDate (timestamp) - data que foi registrado
memberId (String) - registro aleatório
memberUserName (String) - Nome do Usuario
```

Com isso na tela de comunidades, eu listo as comunidades.

```
      db.collection("Communities").get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
               @Override
               public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {    
                        communities.clear();
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                           Communities communitiesList = documentSnapshot.toObject(Communities.class);
                           if(communitiesList.getCommunityTheme().equals(communityTheme))
                                   communities.add(communitiesList);
                            }
                       
  recyclerViewAdapterCommunities.notifyDataSetChanged();
                   }
                   progressDialog.dismiss();
              }
      });
```

Listar as comunidades tudo bem, simples fazer, mas como faço pra saber se a pessoa faz parte e se está ativo na comunidade, após listar uma comunidade. Seria como fazer uma foreign key no mysql, mas não sei como fazer isso no firebase

Existe algum queryselector ou algo do tipo?

Comment: A retórica não esta assertiva. Acho que a escolha do nome Fellow está dificultando a leitura.

Comment: boia vou mudar aqui